# HTML in MODX Manager GUI is not reflecting that on static file

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-templates, modx-chunks

I'm messing around with static files for the first time. I want to make all my templates and chunks static .html and .php files.

However, there is one issue: the changes I make to my files do not seem to appear within the MODX GUI, and vice versa.

For example, on my file `components/templates/hometpl.html` I have:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    [[$scripts]]
<body>
    [[$main-header]]
    <h1>Static File</h1>
    [[*content]]
</body>
</html>
```

But when I click this Template in the MODX Manager I see:

[image]

This does not seem to be a problem with the Chunks, just the Template static files.

I've tried clearing cache to no avail. Would anyone know if theres a way I could sync both what appears in the MODX GUI and what I've actually got on my file?

Comment: Any chance it does show up after saving the template in the manager, or requesting a resource with the template in the front-end?

Comment: Hi @MarkHamstra when I save from the Manager it does update the static file (and make changes to the actual site). However, if I make changes to the static file in my IDE these changes are not reflected back in the Manager. Maybe the Manager is just reading what's saved in the Database and not direct from the static file?

Comment: It should go in both directions, but I was thinking it may need something to trigger it, like a save or request. The path seems to be correct because it updates the file, right? I haven't used static templates myself much, so afraid I'm not sure what else might be the problem.